# Export the dimension of each image to Excel

Tags: python, r, excel, image, matlab

I want to export each dimension (width*height) of hundreds of jpg images to an excel file. So, this excel file will include the name of this image, this image's width, and its height, 3 columns in total. Is there any way I can make it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show the community the efforts you have made to solve the problem yourself. This is SO policy but it also helps both you and the people who read the question produce higher quality content. See [ask]

Comment: I just googled your question and this was one of the top hits in google: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168948-size-of-image. You can start from there and when you have created the size vector use [xlswrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) to write all the size to xls file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows:

```
magick identify -format "%f,%w,%h\n" *jpg > images.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
Bean.jpg,656,354
a-0.jpg,800,600
a-1.jpg,800,600
a-2.jpg,800,600
after.jpg,3840,2160
background.jpg,639,454
badge-1.jpg,1200,761
```